# Exchange API: Get item with attachment's content

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I added an attachment to appointment. But when I try to get appointment by GetItem API method I recieve an appointment without Content node. I don't want to use GetAttachment method because it cost me one additional request to the server. Can I get attachments' content by GetItem method?

```
<t:Attachments>
  <t:FileAttachment>
    <t:AttachmentId Id="AAMkADMzZjU2NjIwLWUzOWItNDFlZC1hNDY5LTIwNTVlODdjM2E4YwBGAAAAAAD3/WwqN7V6Saz7jIDwyy6pBwB0enfRGC/+T5l033DSyikwAAAA5OxPAAB0enfRGC/+T5l033DSyikwAAAA5RW8AAABEgAQAMWyPz5NHRZAmn0OqOSsLew=" /> 
    <t:Name>Attachment.xml</t:Name> 
    <t:ContentType>text/xml</t:ContentType> 
    <t:Size>125</t:Size> 
    <t:LastModifiedTime>2013-01-29T08:40:48</t:LastModifiedTime> 
    <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline> 
    <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto> 
    <t:ContentId /> 
  </t:FileAttachment>
</t:Attachments>
```

Answer (score 0):

There http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565934(v=exchg.80).aspx I have found such information:

> The GetItem operation does not return attachments. It does return
>   metadata about an attached item or file. To return an attachment, use
>   the GetAttachment Operation.

Question is closed.